# Changing multiple column names in a mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, alter

I have many columns in a table with a name starting with field_t and I have to change that to field_c

For example, here is the ALTER TABLE statement for changing the name of one of the columns:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table CHANGE field_t_class field_c_class longtext;
```

How can I change all the columns that follow this pattern instead of doing it in a one by one basis?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can generated the ALTERs like this

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(
           'ALTER TABLE ', C.TABLE_NAME, ' CHANGE ', 
           C.COLUMN_NAME, ' ', REPLACE(C.COLUMN_NAME, 'field_t', 'field_c')
           )
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
WHERE
    C.COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'field[_]t[_]%';
```

You'll also need to append DATA_TYPE etc and based on this CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,
NUMERIC_PRECISION, NUMERIC_SCALE, CHARACTER_SET_NAME and COLLATION_NAME...

Answer (score 2):

Get 1st column names having name like 'field_t%';

```
select C.COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C            
WHERE
C.TABLE_NAME='YourTableName' AND C.COLUMN_NAME like 'field_t%';
```

Then make string of renaming column names like:

Make rename_string as:

```
rename_string= "RENAME COL1 to ReCol1
     RENAME COL2 to ReCol2"
```

Then do :

```
ALTER Table YourTableName {rename_string};
```

Comment: I can't see support for this in ALTER TABLE http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html However, if it works, it is cleaner then mine because the datatype etc isn't needed

Comment: @gbn: Yes sir, it is working. I have tested before on machine then itself I have posted answer.